# Unity: Trying to load and run an fbx animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to load an animation from an fbx file and have it play on a GameObject:

```
TestObject.AddComponent<Animation>();
animation_handler = TestObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
walking_anim = Resources.Load("fbx_anims/walking_anim_test", typeof(AnimationClip)) as AnimationClip;
if(walking_anim == null)
{
    Debug.Log("walking anim not found");
}
walking_anim.legacy = true;
animation_handler.AddClip(walking_anim, "walking");
animation_handler.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;
```

In the game loop, I tried using this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
    if (!(animation_handler.IsPlaying("walking")))
    {
        animation_handler.clip = walking_anim;
        animation_handler.Play("walking");
    }
}
```

It doesnt give any errors, yet it doesn't work either. Anything I'm missing?

EDIT: For clarification: The model stays in the default T-Pose, after pressing 'W'. After inserting Debug.Logs at different points, I can confirm that the Play function is getting called only once, after which IsPlaying always returns true. Yet the "playing" animation causes no visual changes in the model (yes, the bone names are the same).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) component, it is an old legacy component that has been replaced by the much improved [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html) component. There are a lot of good posts on the Internet on how to use it - no need to repeat it here. The important steps are:

1. Add the Animator (not Animation) component to the model.
2. Create an "Animator Controller" in your project and add the clips (like the "walking_anim"). Here you can have a lot of different clips and tell Unity how to interpolate between them by using different parameters.
3. Add the "Animator Controller" to your "Animator" component.
4. Add an "avatar" of your model (usually created when the model is imported).
5. By code alter the parameters of the Animator Controller to tell it which animation clips to play.

It may look like a lot of steps, but it is not so hard and you will quickly have a walking, running, jumping creature on your screen. Good luck!

Comment: So, I tried it and am currently running into the following issue: 
TestObject.AddComponent<Animator>();
mc_animator = TestObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
AnimatorController mc_anim_controller = new AnimatorController();
mc_anim_controller.name = "mc_anim_controller";
AnimatorControllerLayer mc_standardLayer = new AnimatorControllerLayer();
mc_standardLayer.name = "mc_standardLayer";
mc_anim_controller.AddLayer(mc_standardLayer);
mc_anim_controller.AddParameter("currentState", AnimatorControllerParameterType.Int);
AnimatorStateMachine mc_stateMachine = new AnimatorStateMachine();

Comment: continuation:
mc_standardLayer.stateMachine = mc_stateMachine;
AnimatorState idleState = mc_stateMachine.AddState("idle");
AnimatorState walkingState = mc_stateMachine.AddState("walking");
AnimatorStateTransition idleTransition = mc_stateMachine.AddAnyStateTransition(idleState);
AnimatorStateTransition walkingTransition = mc_stateMachine.AddAnyStateTransition(walkingState);
idleTransition.AddCondition(AnimatorConditionMode.Equals, 0, "currentState");
walkingTransition.AddCondition(AnimatorConditionMode.Equals, 1, "currentState");
walkingState.motion = walking_anim;

Comment: mc_stateMachine.AddEntryTransition(idleState);
mc_animator.runtimeAnimatorController = mc_anim_controller;
It says that the "StateMachine for Layer 'mc_standardLayer' is missing", even if I clearly assigned it.
EDIT: I just noticed that all the linebreaks went missing, RIP readability.